# Building XML from excel data with Python

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to build an xml file from an excel spreadsheet using python but am having trouble building the structure. The xml schema is unique to a software so the opening few tags and ending few would be easier to be written to the xml file just as variables, shown below. They are constant so are pulled from the "

I believe the script neeeds to loop through another sheet, being the ".XML Framework" sheet to build the .xml structure as these are the values which will be ultimately changing. The structure of this sheet is provided below.

here is the .xml structure, from which the python is outputting well up to the unique values, and the changing values are shown in bold. This shows just one row of the data from the workbook. When the workbook has a second row, the .xml structure repeats again where it starts with .

**The data structure in the excel sheet ".XML Framework" is:**

```
col 1 = **equals**
col 2 = **74**
col 3 = **Data**"
col 4 = col 3
col 5 = **Name 07**
col 6 = col 5
col 7 = **wstring**
col 8 = /**SM15-HVAC-SUPP-TM-37250-ST**
```

**THIS IS THE DESIRED XML STRUCTURE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<exchange xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://download.autodesk.com/us/navisworks/schemas/nw-exchange-12.0.xsd" units="m" filename="" filepath="">
  <selectionsets>
    <selectionset name="Dev_1">
      <findspec mode="all" disjoint="0">
        <conditions>
            <condition test="**equals**" flags="**74**">
              <category>
                <name internal="**Data**">**Data**</name>
              </category>
              <property>
                <name internal="**Name 07**">**Name 07**</name>
              </property>
              <value>
                <data type="**wstring**">/**SM15-HVAC-SUPP-TM-37250-ST**</data>
              </value>
            </condition>
          </conditions>
    <locator>/</locator>
  </findspec>
</exchange>
```

Here is my attempt from the python:

```
path = (r"C:\\Users\\ciara\\desktop\\")
book = os.path.join(path + "Search_Set.xlsm")
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(book)
sh = wb.get_sheet_by_name('.XML Framework')
df1 = pd.read_excel(book, "<CLEAN>", header=None)

#opening 5 lines of .xml search
print(df1)
cV1 = df1.iloc[0,0] #xml header
print (cV1)
cV2 = df1.iloc[1,0] #<exchange>
print (cV2)
cV3 = df1.iloc[2,0] #<selectionsets>
print (cV3)
cV4 = df1.iloc[3,0] #<selection set name>
print (cV4)
cV5 = df1.iloc[4,0] #<findspec mode>
print (cV5)
cV6 = df1.iloc[5,0] #<findspec mode>
print (cV6)

E = lxml.builder.ElementMaker() 
root = ET.Element(cV1)
doc0 = ET.SubElement(root, cV2)
doc1 = ET.SubElement(doc0, cV3)
doc2 = ET.SubElement(doc1, cV4)
doc3 = ET.SubElement(doc2, cV5)
doc4 = ET.SubElement(doc3, cV6)


the_doc = root(
        doc0(
                doc1(
                        doc2(
                                doc3(
                                    FIELD1('condition test=', name='blah'),
                                    FIELD2('some value2', name='asdfasd'),
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        )   
                    )   

print (lxml.etree.tostring(the_doc, pretty_print=True))

tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write("filename.xml")
```

Comment: Please edit your question to make it clearer - for example what does “where it would repeat from the tag with a new” mean? And you say your code loops through a sheet, but I can’t see any loop - add this code? Adding e.g. imports and any other code needed for a [mre] would be useful to avoid downvotes for non-runnable code when you are asking for help with getting code to work. And add the data needed for the code to try do something useful - all part of providing that [mre]

Comment: Hey @barny I've adjusted to your comments. I was meant to write that I believe the code is required to loop through the data source on another sheet to find the values to fill the xml structure. If its any help i can drop a link to the excel book

Comment: BTW StackOverflow isn’t a code-writing service - you have to show some attempt to solve the problem you ‘neeed’ to solve. So please try to write the loop, and if you can’t get it working then add your code with loop into this question and explain what it doesn’t do that you want it to do. And provide an actual spreadsheet so someone who wants to try your code doesn’t have to spend/waste time creating one. You are supposed to post an [mre] in your question - follow that link, see what it says.